# Flutter: Cannot build android apk

Tags: flutter, release

I have been getting errors building `apk` for flutter. But the app works well while I run it.

I have tried so many fixes like migrating to androidX and upgrading my dependencies but none worked. I recently started getting this error after upgrading flutter. What could be the solution to this?

**Error**

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.                                                                          

1: Task failed with an exception.                                                                                  
-----------                                                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                                                                 
Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences:verifyReleaseResources'.                                            
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade                  
   > Android resource linking failed                                                                               
     /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/d45c258d5b0086b06365ac1a25df0442/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/d45c258d5b0086b06365ac1a25df0442/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:                                                                                                             
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================                                     

2: Task failed with an exception.                                                                                  
-----------                                                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                                                                 
Execution failed for task ':path_provider:verifyReleaseResources'.                                                 
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade                  
   > Android resource linking failed                                                                               
     /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/d45c258d5b0086b06365ac1a25df0442/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     /Users/apple/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/d45c258d5b0086b06365ac1a25df0442/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:                                                                                                             
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

**build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.miraclecentre.bnotion.ben.maf_mentor"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with your flutter version. Get it with `flutter doctor` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your targetSdkVersion to 28.
That's the only fix I've run across.  But when I figure out why that is, I'll come back and update.

EDIT:

update your shared_pref version reference to the most recent one.
After that's done run

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
flutter clean
```

Wait for it to delete older iOS and Android build files.

Then run again:

```
flutter build apk
```

Comment: same error bro. please review my logCat error again. I updated it

Comment: seems like I got some issues with my dependencies but I don't know why. I run the app well and I have properly migrated to androidX too

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by changing `build.gradle` file,
Go to,

```
[project_folder]/external_package/flutter_plugin/[problem_causing_plugin_name]/android/build.gradle/
```

Change `compileSdkVersion 27` to `compileSdkVersion 28`

then, run `Flutter clean` and `Flutter pub get`, and try to create release Apk.